# Can't find my Memory Leak

Tags: c++

**2 Problems:**

1. I ran valgrind on this program an lost around 400 bytes, but I don't know what I did wrong.
2. For some reason, upon the FIRST (and only the first) initialization of a student object (`roster[i]` when `int i = 0`), the loop is only allowing me to pass two parameters into my constructor. I know it sounds strange but the first loop invocation is different from the others.

## HEADER

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Student{

public:
Student();
Student(string ln, string fn, string cn) {setLast(ln);setFirst(fn);setCourse(cn);}
void showInfo(){cout << firstname << " " << lastname << " in " << coursename << endl;} 

protected:
void setLast (string l){lastname = l;}
void setFirst (string f){firstname = f;}
void setCourse (string c){coursename = c;}
string firstname;
string lastname;
string coursename;
};
```

## MAIN

```
int main(){

Student **roster;
int num;
cout << "how many?";
cin >> num;
roster = new Student*[num];
string l,f,c;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
  cout << "\nenter last, first, course: ";
  getline(cin, l);
  getline(cin, f);
  getline(cin, c);
  roster[i] = new Student(l, f, c);
  roster[i]->showInfo();
}
delete [] roster;
};
```

Comment: For `roster[i] = new Student(l, f, c);` there is no corresponding `delete` for each `i`.

Comment: Please don't use C++ as if it was C with fun new syntax.  Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> roster;`, along with `roster.emplace_back( std::make_unique<Student>(l, f, c) );`  You should also test that your calls to `getline` succeeded.

Comment: @n.m. That's utterly unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes there are two problems described in the post, have you checked both?

Comment: @n.m. Ah, my bad -- I misunderstood the second question as something other than what it actually is. Still, this question should just be closed as "too broad"; it's two questions in one.

Comment: Why two levels of indirection here -- `Student **roster`?  All you needed was `Student *roster;...roster = new Student[num];...roster[i] = Student(l, f, c);`  Then your `delete [] roster;` would have worked.  You are overusing `new[]` -- it's bad enough you're using `new[]` at all, but then you go overboard with it.  Your goal is to create a dynamic array of Student, right?  So that translates to `Student *`, not `Student **`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are newing an array and you are newing all students in the array. you made a `new Student*[]` and some `new Student`, but you only `delete[] arr`, you forgot to `delete x`

Before the fix, I want to suggest you to use vector and unique_ptr, which would have prevent all your error in the first place:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> roster;

int num;
cout << "how many?";
cin >> num;
roster.reserve(num);

std::string l,f,c;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
  cout << "\nenter last, first, course: ";
  getline(cin, l);
  getline(cin, f);
  getline(cin, c);

  roster.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Student>(l, f, c));
  roster.back()->showInfo();
}
```

---

Now, the solution for your code. You should put that at the end of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    delete roster[i];
}
delete [] roster;
```

Comment: ahhhh i'm an idiot thanks so much